# iPhone crashing when using Owl Carousel with iFrames

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, owl-carousel

I searched very long time now for this problem but I cant find another one with the same problem.
I created this JsFiddle to demonstrate the problem.

When i open this on an iPhone it will crash in 99/100 cases (sometimes it didnt).
Im really running in a wall on this because i dont know how to debug it.
First the iPhone tries to reload the page until I get the error "A problem repeatedly occured on ..." and theres no more error message.

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/s4gbkwq6/3/)

Android and everything other works just fine.

PS: Give it some time to load the iFrames

```js
$('.carousel2').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    autoplay:false,
    dotsEach: true,
    responsiveClass:true,
    mouseDraggable: false,
    navText : ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            margin: 10,
            dots:true,
            nav:true,
            loop:true
        },
        600:{
            items:1,
            nav:true,
            dots:true,
            margin: 100,
            loop:true
        },
        1000:{
            items:1,
            margin: 100,
            dots:true,
            nav:true,
            loop:true
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css" integrity="sha512-UTNP5BXLIptsaj5WdKFrkFov94lDx+eBvbKyoe1YAfjeRPC+gT5kyZ10kOHCfNZqEui1sxmqvodNUx3KbuYI/A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css" integrity="sha512-OTcub78R3msOCtY3Tc6FzeDJ8N9qvQn1Ph49ou13xgA9VsH9+LRxoFU6EqLhW4+PKRfU+/HReXmSZXHEkpYoOA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />







<div class="carousel2 owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item products_3_img">
    <iframe class="myIframe1" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;" src="https://hajimewatanabe.jp/portfolio/" data-src="" ></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="item products_3_img">
    <iframe class="myIframe2" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;" src="https://cabbi.bo/" data-src=""></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="item products_3_img">
    <iframe class="myIframe3" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;" src="https://renaultespace.littleworkshop.fr" data-src=""></iframe>
  </div>
</div>






<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js" integrity="sha512-gY25nC63ddE0LcLPhxUJGFxa2GoIyA5FLym4UJqHDEMHjp8RET6Zn/SHo1sltt3WuVtqfyxECP38/daUc/WVEA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue in one of my developed sites,
it works fine in all other device like desktop & android phones

It seems like if you have loop: true on owl carousel causes the site to crash on iPhone 14, iPhone 14 Pro and iPhone 14 Pro Max.

To resolve this issue, set loop: false for mobile & true for other desktop sizes. It's a odd bug on Owl Carousel and hopefully they addresses it soon.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on an iphone 8 and can confirm the problem.